# NSTimer selector question

Tags: iphone, selector, nstimer

Greeting !!

I've the following function for example :

```
-(void) doMainBrick
{
    NSTimer * timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
                                                       target:self
                                                     selector:@selector(dropBrick:)
                                                     userInfo:nil
                                                    repeats:YES];
}

-(void) dropBrick:(NSTimer*) timex 
{
    //deal something 
   [self SwitchBrick];
}
```

I wonder if it is possible, if `dropBrick` function do more than `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` ( in my sample above , it is 0.1) , 
another call `dropBrick` happen again (every 0.1 sec fire dropBrick,repeats:YES)?
or no matter what, `NSTimer` will wait for last dropBrick end and then fired?

Answer (score 1):

`NSTimers` are scheduled on the RunLoop.

This means that at each iteration of the RunLoop, the system does the following:

- Checks if there are some timers scheduled for which their fire time has elapsed. If so, fire the associated method.
- Check if some other input sources (like sockets being scheduled on the RunLoop etc) have input data to proceed, if so process them.
- Check if there are events pending, like touch events, and handle them (fire associated actions)
- Perform drawing
- Iterate again

As a consequence:

- The `NSTimer` doesn't care if you call dropBrick by yourself manually in addition to the calls fired by the timer itself
- If the method called by the timer takes more than the specified timeInterval, at the end of the iteration of the RunLoop the method will be fired again immediately, because the fire date of the next call has already elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

One idea i can think of is...

Set the Repeat:NO and let dropBrick recursive call itself. Add some sleep to control the frequency of recursive call.